# Azure Storage: Table vs Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Here is the problem. I have the devices pushing telemetry messages to Azure IoT hub and currently, I save all messages to the Table Storage with partition key device Id and row key telemetry kind. What I want to do is restrict the size of stored data. For instance, the table should keep only up to 50 MB and the should be cleared. What kind of storage should I use for such use case and what are the benefits? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Few follow up questions: 1) Should this data be automatically cleared or are you ok with manually clearing the data? 2) Do you have to clear the data when the size reaches 50 MB or can the data be cleared based on the age i.e. how old the data is? 3) Do you have to use Azure Tables/Blobs or some alternate storage mechanism will be acceptable?

Comment: @GauravMantri 1) This data should be cleared automatically or programmatically(e.g by some job/azure func etc). 2)Yes, this should be based on data size 3) I'm want to use one of these storages. However, if that is not possible with them I will consider other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Azure Tables nor Azure Blobs have the feature where the content automatically gets deleted after a certain size is reached. In fact, I don't think I have come across any cloud storage solution that offers it (I've seen the data gets automatically deleted based on age).

Thus if you want to delete the data once it reaches a certain size, you will have to write some code and schedule it (using either `Functions` or `WebJobs`). That code will find the size occupied and delete the data going over the limit.

Between Blobs and Tables, I am somewhat conflicted. With Blobs, it is much easier to get the storage consumed - You just list the blobs in a container and sum up the size of the blobs. With tables, you will need to keep on fetching entities (i.e. download the data) and calculate the size of that data. But then deleting data from tables is easier as you will be deleting rows (unless you store each record in a separate blob).

If it were not on the data size and rather based on the data age, I would have recommended `Cosmos DB`. Though more expensive than Azure Storage, but you could define TTL at the collection level and based on that policy, the documents will be automatically deleted.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts are the same, that why I'm looking for suggestions here :)

Comment: 1st Rule of Stack Overflow - You don't ask for suggestions ;-)

Comment: Ok, then I'm looking for answers here :)

Comment: Though I am curious as to why you want to restrict based on size considering Cloud Storage is very cheap.

Comment: That is one of the requirements from stakeholders.